# Changing the return type of wrapped Python function

Tags: python, python-typing

I am currently working on an implementation of the Rust Result enum in Python. To be able to just return the classes Ok and Error, I have a wrapper that will turn these into a Result, as shown here:

```py
def result(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            res = Error(e)
        
        if isinstance(res, Error) or isinstance(res, Ok):
            return Result(res)
        else:
            raise ValueError("@result function returned non-result (Ok, Error) object")
    return wrapper
```

However, when wrapping a function with this, it shows its return type as `Ok | Error` even though this is incorrect and it does return a `Result`. I found ways to change the function parameters' signature online, however I want to change the hinted return type. How could I do this?

When hovering over this function in VS Code:

```
@result
def divide(a: int, b: int):
   if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return Error(DivideByZeroError)
   return Ok(a / b)
```

I get the signature `divide(int, int) -> Ok | Error` instead of the correct `divide(int, int) -> Result`.

For clarification, here are the implementations of Ok, Error and Result:

```py
"""
The Result(Error(Exception)) state
"""
@final
class Error:
    def __init__(self, inner: Exception):
        self.inner = inner

"""
The Result(Ok(inner)) state
"""
@final
class Ok:
    def __init__(self, inner: Any):
        self.inner = inner

"""
The python implementation of Rust's Result enum\n
Has two states: either Ok(result) or Error(exception)\n
Note that this class can raise exceptions unlike Option
"""
@final
class Result:
    """
    A Rust-like Result class\n
    Note that you should not create these manually, but instead use the
    @result decorator and return an Ok or Error directly
    """
    def __init__(self, state: Ok | Error):
        self._state = state

    """
    If the state is Ok, returns the inner, else raises the Error
    """
    def unwrap(self):
        if isinstance(self._state, Ok):
            return self._state.inner
        else:
            raise self._state.inner
    
    """
    If the state is Ok, returns the inner, else return the provided 'other'
    """
    def unwrap_or(self, other: Any):
        if isinstance(self._state, Ok):
            return self._state.inner
        else:
            return other
    
    """
    If the state is Ok, return the inner, else run the provided callable
    """
    def unwrap_or_else(self, other: Callable):
        if isinstance(self._state, Ok):
            return self._state.inner
        else:
            return other()
        
    """
    The internal state of the Result, Ok or Error
    """
    @property
    def state(self) -> Ok | Error:
        return self._state

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        if isinstance(self._state, Ok):
            return f"Result(Ok({self._state.inner}))"
        else:
            return f"Result(Error({self._state.inner}))"

    """
    Turns the result of a function into a Result:\n
    If it returns a Result, simply pass this on\n
    If it returns an Ok or Error, wrap this in a Result and return it\n
    If it raises an error, return a Result(Error(Exception))\n
    Else, return a Result(Ok(item))
    """
    @classmethod
    def from_function(cls, func: Callable, *args, **kwargs) -> "Result":
        try:
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            res = e

        if isinstance(res, Result):
            return res
        elif isinstance(res, Ok) or isinstance(res, Error):
            return Result(res)
        elif isinstance(res, Exception):
            return Result(Error(res))
        else:
            return Result(Ok(res))
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for `Error`, `Ok` and `Result`? It's hard to answer a type annotation question here without seeing if e.g. they're generic

Comment: They are all just concrete classes, but I will edit to add the implementation for all 3, although Result is a bit lengthy

Comment: Btw, this already exists: https://github.com/rustedpy/result

Comment: Yes, but I am hoping to make a better and more thorough implementation eventually implementing Option and some other useful types

Comment: You'll definitely want to use generics then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't provide any annotations in the `result` decorator, Pylance assumes that it doesn't change the signature of the function.

You'll need to specify the annotations for `result`. I don't know all the specifics of your classes, but it should look something like

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")

def result(func: Callable[P, Ok | Error]) -> Callable[P, Result]:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you - I will need to look into what ParamSpec does but other than that the implementation works perfectly